# How asyncio.gather() works with different set of test groups?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Here I have four separate group of tests.
I want to run all the tests in each group async and One group after another as there are dependencies.
So groups[0] to finish then run groups[1] etc. But in each group run them asynchronously.

I run the following way but it doesn't work. How should I modify the code to run as expected?
Thanks in advance.

```py
groups = [
    ['tests.test1(driver)', 'tests.test2(driver)', 'tests.test3(driver)'],
    ['tests.test5(driver)', 'tests.test6(driver)', 'tests.test9(driver)'],
    ['tests.test4(driver)', 'tests.test7(driver)', 'tests.test8(driver)'],
    ['tests.test0(driver)', 'tests.test10(driver)']
]
for group in groups:
    async def async_check():
        await asyncio.gather(*[x for x in group])

    asyncio.run(async_check())
```

each test from groups is written like:

```py
def test1(driver):
# some functionality
```

Comment: "...but it doesn't work." So what *does* happen? Do you get an error? Unexpected output? Not all the tests execute? Something else?

Comment: One thing that jumps out immediately is that the items in `groups` are strings, not functions. You can't run a string with `asyncio.gather`. If you fix that problem, I think your code works as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @larsks Actually I could fix it by adding `async` before defining each test function: Like this: async def test1(driver). After it worked fine. Thanks for responding.